# rpm scriptlet ordering for install/remove/upgrade using yum

Tags: rpm, scriptlet

I'm working on a bug in our rpm scriptlets which is probably originating from order in which our scriptlets are executed during package install/removal/upgrade. We are using yum on Redhat Enterprise.

Obviously I first need a good understanding of the order of the rpm scriptlets - and interestingly enough I have not found a good summary of this anywhere.

From what I [gather](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets) this is the scriptlet ordering for *upgrades*:

- `%pretrans` of new package
- `%pre` of new package `prein`
- package install
- `%post` of new package `postin`
- `%preun` of old package
- removal of old package
- `%postun` of old package
- `%posttrans` of new package

However it doesn't list the scriptlet orderings for *installing* a new package not previously on the system (i.e. not an upgrade) and for *removing* one?
From the above ordering I am able to guess how these orderings might look, but I'd like to get some educated opinion on this as well...

Comment: The order in which scriptlets execute (including triggers) is documented in /usr/share/doc/rpm*/triggers for years.

Comment: How can this be correct? Surely 99% of the time an upgrade changes only a few files so how could "removal of old package" inc. say /usr/sbin/nginx run after the install of the new version.  It must be package replace changed files and then some selective package removal of now obsolete files right? Not "removal of old package"?

Comment: @teknopaul "removal of old package" is I think just files specific to the old package not present (or overwritten) in the new package. I think. Still pretty confusing though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Package order for *installing* a single package for the first time:

- `%pretrans` of new package
- `%pre` of new package
- package install
- `%post` of new package
- `%posttrans` of new package

Package order for *removing* a single package:

- `%preun` of old package
- removal of old package
- `%postun` of old package

Answer (score 9):

If you are **installing** two different packages at once (e.g. `primary`, `secondary` ), where one depends on the other (`secondary` requires `primary`), the order is:

- `%pretrans` of `primary`
- `%pretrans` of `secondary`
- `%pre` of `primary`
- installation of `primary`
- `%post` of `primary`
- `%pre` of `secondary`
- installation of `secondary`
- `%post` of `secondary`
- `%posttrans` of `primary`
- `%posttrans` of `secondary`

When **removing** these packages at once, the order is:

- `%preun` of `secondary`
- removal of `secondary`
- `%postun` of `secondary`
- `%preun` of `primary`
- removal of `primary`
- `$postun` of `primary`

Answer (score 1):

Your educated guess is correct - only the steps that are relevant.