# post install dependencies order in spec files

Tags: centos7, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, rhel7

Is it possible to post install Requires dependecies in a spec file on Centos /RHEL 7? 
I tried Requires:  somepackage = 1.0.0.0
The problem is that I need to run a script prior to the dependencies being installed. 
I tried to run that in the %pre section but it appears that it's not executed before the requires' %pre section is run and failing due to a missing license file.

The spec file looks like this:

```
  Name:   MyClient
  Requires:    MyServerPackage = 1.0.0.0

  %pre
  echo "Write license that is needed by MyServerPackage prior to install" > /tmp/mylicense
```

The problem is that I get an error: %pre(MyServerPackage) scriptles failed, exit status 1
Because the /tmp/mylicense is not there at the time MyServerPackages %pre script runs. 
I've also tried to add a package called mylicense and adding a PreReq: mylicense. But no matter what I try I get that error from the check in MyServerPackage %pre.

Comment: after hours of searching I found this possibility that works for RHEL 7+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456217/rpm-scriptlet-ordering-for-install-remove-upgrade-using-yum  I'm open to other/better solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to run a script prior to the dependencies being installed.

That's impossible; the dependency might have been installed two years ago, for all you know.

To answer where I *think* you're going, you can specify that something is required for a specific section with:

```
Requires: MyServerPackage
Requires(pre,preun): MyServerPackage
```

This would tell it (line 1) that to be installed, `MyServerPackage` should always be there. Then line 2 explicitly says it should be there *before* installing or attempting to uninstall this package if you're installing them at the same time. This is useful if, for example, the other package sets up a user name, etc.

Comment: I mark this as the correct answer. Because it is :) However I actually asked the question wrong. The point was that it's actually about a wrapper package. So the dependency is surely not installed earlier. However I could solve my problem by using the %pretrans macro.